# How to fill out 2.8 Visa Application Form of China if you have more than one inviter?

Tags: visas, china

In the online form I put in the two inviters' information but none of them was transferred to the final pdf form -.- seems like a programming mistake.

But what do I do now? Should I just fill out one inviter's info or both separated with `;`? Or leave it blank and hope my invitation letters, where all that info is on, will be enough?

[image: Only one inviter]

Answer (score 1):

I emailed the visa center closest to me and they answered: (translated by me)

> You can enter all inviters.

So, I guess they don't care how I separate them as long as it's obvious.
In my case it's no problem because I just have 2, I will be able to fit their addresses in there too but if there are even more they should really fix their online to PDF "conversion" next time :D

> Update - after I went to the Visa Center

I asked what to do in case I can't fit all inviters' information in these fields. I was told:

> It's enough to only enter the *main* inviter

The others don't have to be on the main form, it's enough to have their information on the separate invitations.

I didn't ask anymore how to determine the "main" inviter (e.g. in case one is visiting multiple people for the same amount of time) because I didn't want to be annoying :D - but I think now most is clear. ;)